# C++ : operator new and default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, new-operator, dynamic-allocation

I'm having trouble understanding how to use dynamic allocation with constructors.

I use in my code a class named graph (which is just a bool 2-d matrix representing the edges between the nodes) with the following constructor/destructor (there others methods, but I dont think it's relevant here) :

```
class graph{

private:
bool** edges;
int size;

public:
graph(int size = 0):size(size){
    edges = new bool*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        edges[i] = new bool[size];
    }
}

~graph(){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        delete [] edges[i];
    }
    delete [] edges;
}

//others methods

};
```

In my main, I want to use dynamic allocation :

```
int main()
{

    int size;
    cout << "Enter graph size :" << endl;
    cin >> size;

    graph g1 = new graph(size);

    //some processing code

    return 0;
}
```

Howewer, I get an error on the instantiation (ie new graph(size) ) :

*invalid conversion from 'graph*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]*

I don't really get what is going wrong, and I'm pretty sure it's a syntax I have already seen in others places.

Actually, I dont really get how memory allocation works with the creation of object.

Here, I use *new* in my constructor to create the bool 2d-matrix, so it's going to the heap, no ?
But if I instanciate the object using the following static instruction :
     graph g1(const_size);

Then it's not suppose to going to the stack ?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

EDIT

Just one last question :

> graph *g1 = new graph(size);
>
> is storing g1 (pointer) on stack, but the object is created on the heap.
>
> graph g1(size);
>
> is creating object on the stack, and g1 is a reference to it.

But in any case, the matrix edges would be on the heap ? Or in the second case it would somehow end on the stack ?

Comment: `graph* g1 = ...` but seriously, *why* do you need dynamic allocation there?

Comment: Truth be told, it was more to understand how I could do it if it was needed. I don't really need it right now.

But for example, if I want a program who can deal with various graph size, without recompiling it each time I want to work with a different size, I would need something like that, no ?

Comment: Not in main. There you can just say `graph g1(42);`

Comment: Why don't you use standard container objects?

Comment: Because I didn't know of it. I'll look into this, thank you.

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should prefix your constructor with `explicit`.

Comment: In order to avoid unwanted conversion from int to graph ? 
Thanks, I didn't know this keyword, I'll think of it from now on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is here:

```
graph g1 = new graph(size);
```

This should be:

```
graph *g1 = new graph(size);
```

The reason is following:

```
new graph(size)
```

is creating new `graph` object and it is returning a pointer to it (with `graph*` type), and:

```
graph g1 = ...
```

is trying to convert that to object to `int` (in order to call `graph(int)` constructor) - so the error is `invalid conversion from 'graph*' to 'int'`.

Now, I suppose this is some kind of exercise, as you shouldn't use allocation on heap in this example. But if you use it anyway, don't ever forget:

```
delete g1;
```

> Actually, I dont really get how memory allocation works with the creation of object.

```
graph *g1 = new graph(size);
```

is storing `g1` (pointer) on stack, but the object is created on the heap.

```
graph g1(size);
```

is creating object on the stack, and `g1` is a reference to it.

P.S. Avoid this:

```
 graph g1 = graph(const_size);
```

This will first create evaluate right side of the statement and it will temporary `graph` object, and it will use copy-constructor to initialize `g1`.

> But for example, if I want a program who can deal with various graph size, without recompiling it each time I want to work with a different size, I would need something like that, no ?

No, you can use stack allocation for this (I've just noticed that in your example, you're using const_size - parameter to the constructor of object allocated on stack doesn't need to be constant):

```
int size;
std::cout << "Enter size: ";
std::cin >> size;
graph g1(size);
```

> Yes, dynamic allocation is not needed here, I just did that code to practice myself. But it would be necessary if I wanted to work with various sized graph without recompiling, no ?

No, look at the example right above this - stack allocated object with variable size - without recompiling.

> I thought we were not supposed to call the destructor ourselves and that it was going to be called anyway when we go out of scope ? (I even read that it was actually bad to call it in some cases, as it might be calling it a second time)

That's true in case of stack allocated objects - the destructor will be called at the end of the scope. However, if you allocate object on heap, the destructor is not called until you call `delete`.

> But in any case, the matrix edges would be on the heap ?

```
    edges = new bool*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        edges[i] = new bool[size];
    }
```

Yes, the entire matrix is allocated on heap.

Comment: Ok thank you a lot. Very clear answer.
Yes, dynamic allocation is not needed here, I just did that code to practice myself.

But it would be necessary if I wanted to work with various sized graph without recompiling, no ?

I thought we were not supposed to call the destructor ourselves and that it was going to be called anyway when we go out of scope ?
(I even read that it was actually bad to call it in some cases, as it might be calling it a second time).


PS : Yeah, I realized the mistake just after writing, I meant 
graph g1(size)

Comment: Thank you, I also edit the original post because I had one last question regarding where is the variable bool** edges.